# php-fpm (PHP-7.1) cannot serve content to nginx on FreeBSD

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, freebsd

I am trying to install `nginx` and `php-fpm` following [this guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-nginx-mariadb-php-lemp-stack-on-freebsd/) on a FreeBSD 11.1 system on a raspberrypi-B+.

Everything behaves as described in the guide up to point 14, which involves
opening a `php` file with information about the system by running

```
phpinfo();
```

At this point, when I open `http://localhost/info.php`, `nginx` times out while waiting for an answer from `php-fpm`. The following message appears in the `nginx` log:

```
[error] 876#100128: *1 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
```

In `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` I have a section for `php` files:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /usr/local/www/nginx;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;    
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

and in `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` I have the line:

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

So I checked if `nginx` can connect to `php-fpm`:

```
$ sudo sockstat -4 -6| grep nginx
```

gives

```
www      nginx      876   3  tcp4   127.0.0.1:80          127.0.0.1:35165
www      nginx      876   6  tcp4   *:80                  *:*
www      nginx      876   9  tcp4   127.0.0.1:60676       127.0.0.1:9000
root     nginx      875   6  tcp4   *:80                  *:*
```

where you can see the incoming connection requesting the page and the outgoing connection to port 9000 (fastcgi).

Looking at `php-fpm` with

```
$ sudo  sockstat -4 -6| grep php-fpm
```

gives

```
www      php-fpm    935   0  tcp4   127.0.0.1:9000        *:*
www      php-fpm    934   0  tcp4   127.0.0.1:9000        *:*
www      php-fpm    934   4  tcp4   127.0.0.1:9000        127.0.0.1:60676
root     php-fpm    933   8  tcp4   127.0.0.1:9000        *:*
```

where you can see the incoming connection.

So `nginx` seems to be connected to `php-fpm` but nothing happens.
In `htop` I can see a master process `php-fpm` with two worker child processes, one of which is taking almost 100% of the CPU time.
After a while `nginx` times out and the worker `php-fpm` stays at 100%
and does not release the socket. The `php-fpm` log file
(`/var/log/php-fpm.log`) does not show any error:

```
[24-Dec-2017 23:09:21] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 933
[24-Dec-2017 23:09:21] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Pid 933 is the master. No log output from the child processes.

So this is what I have found and I do not have any idea of what I should look at next. Do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be related to PHP-7.1. I have installed an older version (PHP-5.6) and the problem disappeared. I leave the question open in case the problem is related to some PHP-7 specific configuration.

Comment: Please post your PHP-FPM configuration file, just the parts that define the listener. Check if it's listening on port 9000 or on a Unix socket - you want the former to match your Nginx configuration.

Comment: Even if you have php-fpm running, you need to have the nginx config to sent php scripts to port 9000. Do you have this? Something like:
`location ~\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
       if (-f $request_filename) {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       }`

Comment: @Gmck: Thanks for the hints. I have added the relevant parts from the configuration files to the question. Also, the output of `sockstat` seems to confirm that the two processes can connect, so I suppose the problem is somewhere else, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Tim: I have edited the question.

Comment: If your PHP-FPM worker process is using 100% CPU, then there is something wrong with its settings or the actual software. It seems that it receives the request, but then something happens that makes it enter a busy loop and never return an answer.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen: Yes, I have the same theory. The same happens if I replace `phpinfo();` with some static HTML content.

Comment: So what happens if you use a current version of PHP (7.2 at this writing)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Good hint. Version 7.2 is not available as a pre-compiled package yet, and compiling it as a port could be take really long on a raspberrypi. I will try this later when the package is available.